# https non www redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm trying to get all my URLs to redirect to `https://` without `www.`

If someone puts in `www.` or `http://` or `http://` they are redirected to `https://` the problem comes if they put `https://www.` then it doesn't redirect to `https://website`

I'm using the following in my `htaccess`, any suggestions?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: doesn't make much sense. `if (https is off and the host has www) then redirect`, followed by `if (https is not on, aka it's off) then redirect`.

Answer (score 4):

This single rule can take care of both requirements:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to remove both of you shown rules and test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: thanks, it seems to work in everything apart from chrome where it still keeps the www.

Comment: That is due to old cache in Chrome. Clear all cache data and retest.

Comment: @Andy I'm sure it's not just Chrome. I also have been faced with a similar situation in other browsers.

Comment: Yes almost all the browsers cache URLs aggressively after a `301` redirect. Therefore best way to test them is using command line tools like `curl`, `wget` or else use chrome dev tool with caching disabled.

Comment: @Andy Have a read at this which helped me https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS for a similar situation. Sidenote: I hope you don't mind my posting here anubhava. I can move it to the OP's comments section if you like.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Your comments are most welcome here and will help future readers of this question.