# Access a subdomain not through Cloudflare

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, dns, cloudflare

So I have 1 site that has its own EV SSL Certificate. (mysite.com)
I have it on "A" Server and I use Cloudflare for this site.

Then I have created a subdomain for this site (subdomain.mysite.com)
and the files for this "subdomain" I have it on another server "B".

So I have created the "a" record for that subdomain on
cloudflare so it can forward to "B" Server.

I didn't copied the EV SSL files from A Server to B Server since I want this subdomain not to use SSL certificate.

But my problem is, when I try to access my subdomain.mysite.com it:

1. Redirects me to "https" connection
2. Browser says: "Privacy Error... Attackers might be trying to steal your information from subdomain.mysite.com"

Which are your recomendations for this issue?

Should I copy the SSL files also on the "B" server ? 

Is there a way to not use cloudflare for the "subdomain" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355861/disable-ssl-https-redirection-apache2/33379482#33379482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing this:

1. Go to Cloudflare account
2. Go to Crypto
3. On SSL (with SPDY) change "strict" to "flexible"

Solved